# How do I fix the "Configuration with name 'compile' not found" Error when building my Fabric Mod

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, minecraft-fabric

When trying to build the Fabric ExampleMod([link](https://github.com/FabricMC/fabric-example-mod)) I get this Error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\Programmieren\Minecraft\Mods\Advanced Totems\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '0.5-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > Configuration with name 'compile' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I have followed this tutorial([link](https://youtu.be/SqMGHoBOeYY))

What I have tried:

- Updating Java to Version 16
- ./gradlew --stop
- starting debug mode

Please help!

Comment: Probably the version of the `fabric-loom` plugin is not compatible with your Gradle version. Gradle removed the `compile` configuration with version 7.0 (people have been told to no longer use it since Gradle 3.4). Maybe upgrading the `fabric-loom` plugin to version 0.9 will help.

Comment: @ThomasKläger So if you're not supposed to use compile, what are you supposed to use instead?

Comment: @StevenJOwens the answer is in the [Gradle Upgrade Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal): instead of `compile` use `implementation` .

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks, but there's no occurrence of the string "compile" in either of the two build.gradle files in my project.  Hm, I wonder if I need to upgrade one of the dependencies...

Comment: @StevenJOwens it can be an outdated plugin that tries to add dependencies to the `compile` configuration - this was the problem the OP most probably had.

Comment: @StevenJOwens Were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: @bunchesNbunches It was indeed, as Thomas Kläger suggested, an outdated plugin/dependency.